# MonthCalendar в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте!

У меня возник один вопрос в Delphi. Как сделать, чтобы в календаре MonthCalendar по поставленному условию закрашивалась красным цветом одна из ячеек (т.е. число в календаре). Помогите, плиз! Спасибо...

Answer (score 1):

Используйте процедуру BoldDays

**Добавлено из комментария.**

А вот так работать должно:

```
var
  Dates: array of Cardinal;
  k: Integer;
  i: Cardinal;
begin
  k := 0;
  with DBGrid.DataSource.Dataset do
  begin
    First;
    while not EoF do
    begin
      Inc(k);
      SetLength(Dates, k);
      Dates[k - 1] :=DayOf(FieldByName('Data').AsDateTime);
    end;
  end;
  MonthCalendar.BoldDays(Dates, i);
end;
```

Comment: Да...все хорошо получается. А сейчас мне надо сделать чуть-чуть по другому. Итак, у меня на форме расположен MonthCalendar и DBGrid. В DBGrid-е есть поле с датами(поле Data). Так мне надо сделать, чтобы все даты которые находятся в таблице(т.е. весь список дат) выделялись в календаре. Помогите!

Comment: Дальше элементарно, примерно так
var 
  Dates: array of Cardinal;
  k: Integer;
begin
  k := 0;
  with DBGrid.DataSource.Dataset do
  begin
    First;
    while not EoF do
    begin
      Inc(k);
      SetLength(Dates, k);
      Dates[k-1] := FieldByName('Data').AsDate;
    end;
  end;
  MonthCalendar.BoldDays(Dates, 0);
end;

Comment: Не знаю почему, но указывает ошибку на MonthCalendar.BoldDays(Dates, 0), вернее то, что в скобках....

Answer (score 0):

Этот компонент построен на основе контрола из comctl32.dll. Либо там должен быть метод SetColor (или подобный), который позволит выбрать цвет фона выделенной даты. Либо прямо получить хэндл окна, и вызвать [функцию](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774716(v=vs.85).aspx) WinAPI

Comment: Не получается((( Мне нужно, чтобы закрашивались те ячейки дат, которые удовлетворяют условию.